# Uploading Android library to Maven Central

Tags: android, maven, android-library, bintray, maven-central

When using Android Studio, I am aware that you can add dependencies like so:

[image: Android Studio project structure window]
Then you can search to find repositories, and Android Studio will notify you when you need to update the version of your library dependency.

[image: Android Studio library update notification]

I also have a library (currently on Bintray), but it doesn't appear in the library dependency list (as in the first screenshot) - is this because the list shows libraries from Maven Central?

If so, how would I go about putting my library on Maven Central? I have looked at some results on Google, but different blog pages and tutorials show different steps, so it can be very confusing.

Since my library ([view on GitHub](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/MaterialDesignUtils)) is using the [Novoda Bintray Release plugin](https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release), I have tried following the instructions from [this wiki page](https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release/wiki/Add-support-for-syncing-to-maven-central) to add my library to Maven Central, but I'm not really sure where to go from here.

So, to summarise, what I am asking is:

1. Do I need to upload my library to Maven Central?
2. If so, how would I do that? Should I carry on using the Novoda plugin, or should I switch to something easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

The current default maven repository for android gradle plugin is not Maven Central, but [JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter), and this is probably what you are looking for. If you currently have a library deployed to your maven repository on Bintray, publishing to JCenter (also managed by Bintray) is very easy and requires clicking a button, describing your library and waiting for approval. The whole process is neatly explained [here](https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/uploads/uploads_includingyourpackagesinjcenter.html).

Comment: I already have my project up on JCenter and it's deployed to the Maven repository there. However, what do I need to do to get my library to appear on the list, as shown in my first screenshot